# Attribute without value in AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've written a directive with an isolate scope.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope {
            attr1: '@',
            attr2: '@',
            noValueAttr: // what to put here?
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            // how to check here if noValueAttr is present in mark-up?
        }
    };
});
```

the html could be

```
<my-directive attr1='...' attr='...' ... no-value-attr>
```

or

```
<my-directive attr1='...' attr='...' >
```

I am wondering how to use (and have the directive detect if it's there or not) an optional attribute which has no assigned value. Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just use `attrs.hasOwnProperty('noValueAttr')` in the link function to test whether the attribute is present or not.

Don't forget the attribute in markup would be `no-value-attr`, not `noValueAttr` like you showed.

```
 link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
           if (attrs.hasOwnProperty('noValueAttr'))
              // attribute is present
           else 
              // attribute is not present

    }
```

Comment: Do I need to place `noValueAttr` in the isolate scope? If it is, what would I place after the colon in `noValueAttr: ...`?

Comment: @menorah84: Nope. You don't have to

Comment: @menorah84 You don't need to place all attributes in the isolate scope definition object. I tend to keep all constant string valued attributes and boolean/no-value attributes out of it, myself. Just use `attrs` instead.

Comment: when attribute is present `scope.attribName=true` else `scope.attribName=false` provide the variable I need in my template. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but there is that way to:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
  scope.noValueAttr = scope.$eval(attrs.noValueAttr) || 'default value';
}
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question: How to map value-less attributes that are truthy if present and false if not present to a boolean $scope variable.