# Properties Without Value in AngularJS Directive Tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to capture a single word property (one without value) in an AngularJS directive tag, instead of requiring a value be assigned to it, and have that value available in the `Controller`?

For example:

```
<my-input type="radio" checked></my-input>
```

... instead of requiring `checked="true"` be typed.

There is a solution for accessing these values in the `link` of a directive ([Attribute without value in AngularJS directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285925/attribute-without-value-in-angularjs-directive)), but it is unclear to me how I can gain access to these values in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attrs in the controller much the way you can in scope.

```
app.directive('myInput', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function($scope,$element,$attrs){
        }
    };
}]);
```

Look at [the $compile/directive definition object official doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object), but scroll down to the section on the controller constructor function.

> The controller is injectable (and supports bracket notation) with the following locals:
>
> $scope - Current scope associated with the element
>
> $element - Current element
>
> $attrs - Current attributes object for the element
>
> $transclude - A transclude linking function pre-bound to the correct transclusion scope

Answer (score -1):

In HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="msngModel" ng-change='saveChanges(msngModel)' ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
```

In Controller

```
scope: {
                msngModel: "=?", // other scope items

            },
```